# Is this implied by the strict convexity of $f$?

Tags: functions, inequality, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Extending from [If $f$ is strictly convex in a convex set, show it has no more than 1 minimum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337090/if-f-is-strictly-convex-in-a-convex-set-show-it-has-no-more-than-1-minimum) and [Examples of $f$ strictly convex, either with one minimizer or with no minimizer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540554/examples-of-f-strictly-convex-either-with-one-minimizer-or-with-no-minimizer)

Can we have the same minimisers $(x_1^*,x_2^*,\cdots,x_n^*)$ for $$f\left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} x_j\right)$$ and $$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} f\left( x_j\right)?$$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$ is **strictly convex** and $n$ is finite natural number.

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking whether the two quantities
$$f\left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} x_j\right)\tag1$$
and
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} f\left( x_j\right)?\tag2$$
**can** have the same minimizers, the answer is yes: Let $a$ be the minimizer of $f$, and set $x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_n=a$.

If you're asking whether the two quantities (1) and (2) **must** have the same minimizers, the answer is no. The quantity (1) is minimized by any $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ for which $\sum x_i= na$, whereas $x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_n=a$ is the only minimizer for (2). If $a>0$, then the second solution set is a proper subset of the first.

Comment: Agreed. What changes are required to be done if one wants an **Yes** for the case of **must** in your answer?

Comment: Can you also look at this, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273653/determining-type-of-a-function-to-fulfill-the-requirement, question and try to address the same? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @stud_iisc I think a necessary and sufficient condition for **must** is that the minimizer of $f$ be zero (since by assumption $f$ is defined only for non-negative $x$).

Comment: @stud_iisc I looked at and wrote an answer to your other question.